# type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set the from List to Map i got this error.

I am getting the data from the Firestore, Below you can see the query and the output.

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> transactionData = [];
  List accountList = [];
  List availableAccount = [];

getData() async{
    final dataDB = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('TransactionData').doc(getUid()).get();
    snapshot = dataDB;
    final Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    documentData.forEach((key, value) {
      availableAccount.add(key);
    });

    for(int j=0;j<availableAccount.length;j++){
      transactionData = (documentData[availableAccount[j]] as List).map((accountList) => accountList as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();
      accountList.add(transactionData);
    }
    _cards = accountList;
    print('Cards: $_cards');
    setState(() {
      _data = _cards![0];
    });
  }
```

```
Cards: [[{categoryName: Education, uid: LNM6JQuoKCPIANTyQHMKWLIzl5m1, amount: 3,000.00, lastUpdatedDate: 25-08-2022, createdDate: 25-08-2022, toAccountId: , type: Credit, transfer: N, accountId: 21Aug5298Sav, auto: Y, accountName: null, transactionId: deb1621, categoryLogo: assets/images/Education.png, untagged: N, categoryBackgroundColor: 0xffFFA2C0, currency: INR, transactionDate: 25-08-2022}, {categoryName: Education, uid: LNM6JQuoKCPIANTyQHMKWLIzl5m1, amount: 300.00, lastUpdatedDate: 25-08-2022, createdDate: 25-08-2022, toAccountId: , type: Debit, transfer: N, accountId: 21Aug5298Sav, auto: Y, accountName: null, transactionId: deb5366, categoryLogo: assets/images/Education.png, untagged: N, categoryBackgroundColor: 0xffFFA2C0, currency: INR, transactionDate: 25-08-2022}, {categoryName: Travelling, uid: LNM6JQuoKCPIANTyQHMKWLIzl5m1, amount: 100.00, lastUpdatedDate: 24-08-2022, createdDate: 24-08-2022, toAccountId: , type: , transfer: N, accountId: 21Aug5298Sav, auto: Y, accountName:<…>
```

can someone please help me how to resolve this, i am getting error when i set '_cards![0]' to '_data'.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Show us how you defined _data

Comment: what type are _data and _cards ?

Comment: List? _cards;
  Map? _data;

Comment: List<Map<String, dynamic>>   _cards   .   Map<String, dynamic> _data. define these two parameter like this. see can fix your problem?

Comment: nope still getting the same error.

Comment: I see cards is this: Cards: [[{... . this means cards is not List<Map> but it is List<List<Map>>. is it? or it just typo mistake? could please add _cards![0] result  in full data too ?

Comment: This is what i get for _cards![0]  =>
Cards: [{categoryName: Education,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect `_cards` be a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` but it is not. It is a `List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>` and try to pass first item of it which is `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` to _data which is `Map<String, dynamic>` and this is a problem. If you wanna pass any value from _cards to _data should be like this:

```
_data = _cards![0][0];
```

if you want convert `List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>` to `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, do this:

```
List<String> newCards = [];
          
for (var item in _cards) {
  newCards = [...newCards, ...item];
}
```

and then:

```
_data = newCards[0];
```

Comment: is it possible to convert from List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> to List<Map<String, dynamic>>

Comment: if you provide the full List of Cards so I can see all the information in it, I could can convert it.

Comment: i have updated my collection image, what is am trying here is i have a collection in that for example i have 2 arrays(which is dynamic), i am trying to display this data into this [https://pub.dev/packages/card_selector] package.

Comment: Thanks @eamirho3ein, i appreciate your effort, its working now.

Comment: my data is not correctly. Actually my data is like this _cards = [[array1][array2]]